# Passing data from a pivot page to a specific panorama item

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to pass data from a pivot page to a specific point in a panorama in a Windows Phone Application, and it is not working.

I created a text box in my pivot page, where the user has to enter a name. As soon as the user taps on the Save button (which is located in an application bar), the name is  transferred to a text block (which is located in the panorama). Unfortunately, this is not functioning as when I enter a name, the app goes back to the main page of the panorama and does not display the saved name.

This is my attempted code:

Code in Pivot Page:

```
private void SaveNewName(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        string NewName;
        NewName = NameBox.Text;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?msg="+ NewName, UriKind.Relative) ); 

    }
```

Code in panorama (MainPage.xaml.cs)  :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        /*if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();

        }*/

        base.OnNavigatedTo(e); 
        string msg = "";

        if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue(msg, out msg))
        {  
            displayName.Text = msg;
        }  


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying your key as an empty string variable as opposed to the key you used in the Uri, and then trying to write back out to it.

```
NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg)
```

Will probably do the trick.  May also be worth defining your navigation keys as constants then referencing them in both the Uri creation and the population from the dictionary.